# Proving irregularity of $a^{k!}$ using Nerode's theorem

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

> Use Nerode's theorem to prove that the following language $L$ is not regular:
>
> $$ L=\{a^{k!} \mid 1\leq k\} $$

Here is my attempt:

Let $A$ be an infinte set of words s.t-  $$ A=\{a^n \mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$$

Then we shall consider 2 words from the set $a^{i!}$ and $a^j$ s.t-
$$ i!\leq n, i!\ne j$$

$$a^{i+1} \longrightarrow a^{i!}\cdot a^{i+1}=a^{(i+1)!}\in L$$
$$a^j\cdot a^{i+1}=a^{j+i+1}\notin L$$

I understand my attempt is not correct since when multiplying $a^{i!}\cdot a^{i+1}$ the exponent doesn't multiply . I cant seem to overcome this obstacle and would appreciate help.

Comment: I don't understand your attempt, since it doesn't contain any words.

Comment: Also, what is your question? Is it whether your attempt is correct or not? We typically don't grade homework solutions, which is your TA's job.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I edited my attempt and clarified my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prove the following using Myhill-Nerode: If $x_n$ is a non-decreasing sequence, and the differences $x_{n+1} - x_n$ are not bounded, then the language $\{a^{x_n}\}$ is not regular.

That covers lots of problems that you will find in a course, like your n!, or $a^p$ where p is prime, or $a^{n^2}$, or any infinite subsequence of such sequences.

Someone else asked about the language $\{0^{2^n}\}$. Same solution.